# Test_bit macro in C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, keyboard

I'm trying to read input of a linux device via ioctl() and I saw on many example of code with the "test_bit" macro but the only code I found about it is this : `#define test_bit(bit, array) (array[bit / 8] & (1 << (bit % 8)))` and it does not work. I came to the conclusion that there is probably something to include in my class in order to have this macro. 
Does anybody can help me about this it's been a few days that I'm stuck with that problem ? 
Thanks

Edit : 
Here is the code I'm running :

```
void test(){
uint8_t key_b[KEY_MAX/8 + 1];
/* the events (up to 64 at once) */
const char *keyboard = "/dev/input/keyboard0";
int keybrdToCapture;
int yalv;
keybrdToCapture = open(keyboard, O_RDONLY);

memset(key_b, 0, sizeof(key_b));
ioctl(keybrdToCapture, EVIOCGKEY(sizeof(key_b)), key_b);

for (yalv = 0; yalv < KEY_MAX; yalv++) {

    if (test_bit(yalv, key_b)) {
        switch ( yalv)
            {
            case 0x1c :
                dial->setMessage("Enter");
                dial->show();
                break;
            case 0x66 :
                dial->setMessage("Home");
                dial->show();
                break;
            case 0x3b :
                dial->setMessage("F1");
                dial->show();
                break;
            case 0x3c :
                dial->setMessage("F2");
                dial->show();
                break;
            default:
                dial->setMessage("Unknow for now");
                dial->show();
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How does `#define test_bit(bit, array) (array[bit / 8] & (1 << (bit % 8)))` not work? It seems not to be anything provided by a standard C/C++ libary. Hence, you may define it in your own source. (Though, `#define`s with all-lowercase identifiers - not good.) Usually, macros may be re-defined. Friendly compilers provide at least a warning in this case. If in doubt, you may enclose it in `#ifndef test_bit` and `#endif // test_bit`.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I'm quite new to c++ and linux and from what I've understood this code is supposed to check that a specific bit is set to 1 in a specific byte. (Maybe I'm totaly wrong I did not get many help on the explanation of this from now).But when I press a key in debug I can see one bit in my byte change from 0 to 1 but I never enter in my test_bit condition. Maybe it's is simply a problem of misunderstanding.

Comment: `array[bit / 8]` divides bit number by 8 to address the proper byte of `array`. `bit % 8` computes remainder of division by 8 (actually, separates last 3 bits storing 0 ... 7). `1 << (bit & 8)` shifts 1 to the position of computed bit. Finally, `(array[bit / 8] & (1 << (bit % 8)))` masks out all bits except the addressed. If it is set the expression becomes not 0 (which is interpreted as not false i.e. true). Otherwise, the expression becomes 0 (which is interpreted as false). Of couse, this macro is dedicated to be used in an appropriate `if ()` or something similar.

Comment: `array` should be a variable (or expression) with type array of `unsigned char`. (`char` or `signed char` might work as well but signed-ness can cause issues.)

Comment: From your previous comment I change with this hoping it's better :`#ifndef test_bit
#define test_bit(bit, array) (array[bit / 8] & (1 << (bit % 8)))
#endif`. From what you are telling me it should be working... In debug my array look like something like : \000\000\000\010\000\ is it normal ?

Comment: I edit my post with the entire code I'm trying to run. It's supposed to open a dialog when I press a button. But I should have something wrong.

Comment: So, this is what I finally found out: The loop goes from 0 to `KEY_MAX - 1` and checks for every value whether the corresponding bit is set in `key_b`. If so, the resp. number is reported as key press. (Multiple keys may be pressed at once (if the H/W can manage this).) The `test_bit()` followed by `switch()` confused me somehow. A much simpler sample, I found in [Get Input Keys Status Under Linux](http://baruch.siach.name/blog/posts/linux_input_keys_status/). This gave me enlightment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a small sample showing how `test_bit` could be used. (I re-named it `TEST_BIT` and explain below why.):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#define TEST_BIT(bit, array) (array[bit / 8] & (1 << (bit % 8)))

int main()
{
  unsigned char data[] = {
    (unsigned char)0xde,
    (unsigned char)0xad,
    (unsigned char)0xbe,
    (unsigned char)0xef
  };
  enum { nData = sizeof data / sizeof *data };
  enum { nDataBits = 8 * nData };
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < nDataBits; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Bit " << std::setw(2) << i << ": "
      << (TEST_BIT(i, data) ? 1 : 0) << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Bit  0: 0
Bit  1: 1
Bit  2: 1
Bit  3: 1
Bit  4: 1
Bit  5: 0
Bit  6: 1
Bit  7: 1
Bit  8: 1
Bit  9: 0
Bit 10: 1
Bit 11: 1
Bit 12: 0
Bit 13: 1
Bit 14: 0
Bit 15: 1
Bit 16: 0
Bit 17: 1
Bit 18: 1
Bit 19: 1
Bit 20: 1
Bit 21: 1
Bit 22: 0
Bit 23: 1
Bit 24: 1
Bit 25: 1
Bit 26: 1
Bit 27: 1
Bit 28: 0
Bit 29: 1
Bit 30: 1
Bit 31: 1
```

[<kbd>Life demo on coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc64093586ffaa1)

Please, note:

1. Function-like macros are a bad choice in C++. Much better are inline functions because macros are not type-safe but functions are. In this case, the appropriate alternative could be e.g.:

   ```
   inline bool test_bit(unsigned bit, unsigned char *array)
   {
     return array[bit / 8] & (1 << (bit % 8)) != 0;
   }
   ```
2. Macros should be named with uppercase exclusively. Macros are processed before the actual C++ compiling starts. Hence, they are completely beyond any defined namespace. This can have surprising effects. Hence, the uppercase naming to make them a bit exclusive. (Or, better use inline-functions instead whenever you can.)
3. The macro isolates a bit from the byte array. So, the isolated value may be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 depending on which bit is tested (the result of `1 << (bit % 8)`) if the resp. bit is set. This is not a problem as long as the truth value is needed as everything != 0 is counted as true. If 0 or 1 is intended the result of `test_bit()` or `TEST_BIT()` should be compared with 0 additionally.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanaition. I take your advices, as a beginner it is very useful ! I understand better what I'm doing now.

Comment: Can you please explain me what those two lines are doing exactly ? `enum { nData = sizeof data / sizeof *data };
  enum { nDataBits = 8 * nData };`

Comment: `sizeof data / sizeof *data` divides size of array by size of first element. The result is the number of elements in array `data`. Assigning it to an enumerator (of an anonymous `enum`) makes it a real compile time constant (the only real named constants which are supported in C/C++ - prior these new fancy `constexpr` things). In this case, I could have used `const size_t nData = sizeof data / sizeof *data;` as well but in other cases not. E.g. an array dimension must be a compile time constant. The `enum` thing would work there but `const size_t nData` not.

Comment: Another option would have been to make a `#define NDATA sizeof data / sizeof *data`. Now, we're back at "Prevent macros when ever you can." ;-)

Comment: So the first line give you the number of bytes and the second the number of bit if I understand well. But I don't understand what you mean by "compile time constant"

Comment: The first line gives the number of bytes because element type of array is byte(-like). I said it more general: "number of elements" as this trick works for every type of C++ array.

Comment: What about the "compile time constant" ? What does this mean ? And I assume there is a reason to divide the size of the array by 1 can you tell me why didn't you just used `sizeof data` ? (Sorry for all those questions but I would like to improve and understand what I do)

Comment: Actually, `sizeof data` would have returned the size of array in bytes. You may think: Why such complicated? Why this `/ sizeof *data` though it does not change the result? I think the opposite way: `sizeof data / sizeof *data` is a way to get the number of elements for arrays regardless of element type - that's why I always do it this way. (I'm used to it.) And don't forget: This works for arrays but if arrays are passed as function arguments then they decay to pointers. This trick does not work for pointers...

Comment: You may do: `char a[10];` - that's trivial. You may do `char b[5 * 2];` as well but you may not do `int a = 5; char c[a * 2];` This is because `5 * 2` can be (and is) computed by compiler "at compile time". Looking into the machine code, you would find the result 10. `a * 2` _may not_ be computed by the compiler as `a` is a variable (and may change at run-time). Hence, the compiler has to produce the ful code for computation at runtime. Arrays with unknown size at compile time are not allowed in C++ (not by standard).

Comment: Thank you for all those explaination. It is lot more clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but ... I didn't look up EVIOCGKEY in detail, so this is just a guess, but could it be an endianness issue? Maybe the bits aren't where you're expecting them to be in the array. How about something like:

```c
uint64_t key_b = 0;
...
ioctl(keybrdToCapture, EVIOCGKEY(sizeof(key_b)), &key_b);
```

and use something like this for the test:

```c
#define test_bit(bit, array) ((array) & ((uint64_t)1 << (bit)))
```

(or an appropriate C++ function, whatever suits your needs)

Anyway, can you be a bit more specific than "it does not work"?